# Unique on three different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unique

I am working on a Ruby on Rails web application. I want to validate the uniqueness of more than one field together. How can i do this?

For example: I have a model named `waiting` with three fields:

`project_id` `category_id` and `user_id`

I want to ensure that i won't have two identical rows in **all** three fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just to:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:project_id, :category_id]
```

+

```
add_index :waitings, [:project_id, :category_id, :user_id], :unique => true
```

Read API:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index

Answer (score -1):

It's not pretty but this works for me:

```
class Waiting < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :must_be_unique

  def must_be_unique
    if self.class.where(project_id: project_id, category_id: category_id, user_id: user_id).exists?
      errors.add(:base, 'Must be unique')
    end
  end
end
```

Of course you could just use a unique key in your db schema and then catch the relevant exceptions on the rare occasion you need to.

Comment: Fair enough. It should be possible to implement a new EachValidator for this; I'd certainly like to see one.